# Javascript Pixel Manipulation: These aren't my colors

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I know questions like this have been asked several time, but I have yet to find just what I'm looking for.  I am reading an image into a canvas object (in javascript) and trying to manipulate some specific pixels.  For example, I am looking for the color RGB: 224 64 102, and trying to change this to a different color.

I can apply greyscale to the image, so I know the manipulation works, but the code is not finding any pixels with this color (that Adobe Illustrator said was the RGB color).  I'm hoping I'm just missing a small detail.  The code is below, hopefully someone will see it.

Thanks!

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("testcanvas");
            var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');


            imgObj = new Image();
            imgObj.src = "ss.jpg";
            //imgObj.width = 200;
            //imgObj.height = 200;
            var imgW = imgObj.width;
            var imgH = imgObj.height;
            canvas.width = imgW;
            canvas.height = imgH;
            canvasContext.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);

            var imgPixels = canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0, imgW, imgH);

            //hash_table = {};

             for (var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++) {
                for (var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++)
                    {
                   var i = (y * imgPixels.width + x) * 4;
                     //Want to go from:
                     //E04066
                     //224 64 102 -> to
                     //134 135 185

                     if(imgPixels.data[i] == 224 && imgPixels.data[i+1] == 64 && imgPixels.data[i+2] == 102) {
                        imgPixels.data[i] = 134;
                        imgPixels.data[i+1] = 135;
                        imgPixels.data[i+2] = 185;
                     }

                     //To greyscale:
                     /*
                     var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
                     imgPixels.data[i] = avg;
                     imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg;
                     imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
                     imgPixels.data[i + 3] = 255;
                    */
                }
            }
            canvasContext.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
            //color_count = 0;
            //for(key in hash_table) {
            //  color_count++;
            //}
            //console.log(color_count);
            //console.log(hash_table);
            return canvas.toDataURL();

        });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="testcanvas"></canvas>

<img src="ss.jpg" id="testimage"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried with an all-(224 64 102)-image?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.

If that file, ss.jpg is local then it won't work. I imagine that's the case.

Search for canvas cross-origin on SO or Google for more information on that. There's a lot out there. Here's a bit of an explanation:

http://simonsarris.com/blog/480-understanding-the-html5-canvas-image-security-rules

Here's a site about enabling it on your server:

http://enable-cors.org/

---

Otherwise, your code works. Here is the same code converting a tiny red dot into a tiny green dot:

http://jsfiddle.net/RBaxt/

Comment: I have a local server running (MAMP) with the image in the same directory as the HTML file.  I'm not getting an error message, but that doesn't necessarily mean this isn't the problem.  If what I'm understanding is true, I cannot do this locally, regardless of the fact I am running a server under localhost.  Is this the case?  I appreciate the help, and I think you hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas really don't work with `.JPG` format. You have to convert your image into `.PNG` using any picture editing tool like Photoshop. Your code works well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are loading an Image that is not ready to be painted. Below I have updated your code above, though I have not test it but I feel it could lead you somewhere

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById("testcanvas");
        var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');


        imgObj = new Image();
        imgObj.src = "ss.jpg";
        //imgObj.width = 200;
        //imgObj.height = 200;
        var imgW = imgObj.width;
        var imgH = imgObj.height;
        imgObj.onload = function(){
           //Put the pixel manipulation code here;
           // This ensures the image has been loaded before it is accessed. 
        }
```